# extract paragraphs from HTML page

Tags: java, jsoup, paragraphs

Using Jsoup, I want to extract all paragraphs from an HTML page, i.e. whatever is between `<p>` and `</p>`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Can'y you just do:

```
myDocument.getElementsByTag('p')
```

[JSoup getElementsByTag](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByTag%28java.lang.String%29)

You can then iterate over the returned elements and get their data/text/ownText / whatever you think is most relevant for what you want to do.

[JSoup Element.text()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29)

Comment: after I wanted to extract the urls that are in the paragraphs so, i can have the urls but not the reels urls.


I want this: not that

Comment: You could iterate the returned collection and see if any of the elements are <a> tags.

Comment: I want to get parent p tags only. I.e if any p has p as parent it should not be included in return list of paragraph.